# XML and DTD's error that will not go away

Tags: xml, xml-validation, dtd

I have a quick question what the hell I am I doing wrong here. I have my XML and DTD and no matter what I do I keep getting the same error. please help. this is for a class i had altered this code so many times so if there is anything missing please feel free to tell me.

This is my XML, sation, and nameofshows, are where I am getting my errors...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tvlisting SYSTEM "tvlisting.dtd">

<tvlisting>
    <changelocation>
        <provider>Cox, ComCast, Charter, Dishnetwork, DirectTV</provider>
    </changelocation>
    <date>July 1, 2018</date>
    <time>2:55pm</time>
    <searchlisting>
        <channelsearch>CBS, ABC, NBC, FOX, PBS, CW, MNT, ION, TELMUN, UNI, AandE,AMC,ANIMAL,
            BBC,ETC.</channelsearch>
    </searchlisting>
    <tabs>pick by genre</tabs>
    <legend>name and time show airs</legend>
    <tableofshows>
        <sation>AMC</sation>
        <name>Limitless</name>
        <timeaired>1:00pm-3:00pm</timeaired>
        <sation>ANIMAL</sation>
        <name>Extinct or Alive</name>
        <timeaired>1:00pm-3:00pm</timeaired>
        <sation>BBC</sation>
        <name>Black Hawk Down</name>
        <timeaired>1:00pm-4:00pm</timeaired>
        <sation>BET</sation>
        <name>Tyler Perry's Good Deeds</name>
        <timeaired>1:00pm-3:00pm</timeaired>
        <sation>BRAVO</sation>
        <name>Kandi Koated Nighs</name>
        <timeaired>2:30-3:00pm</timeaired>
    </tableofshows>
    <!-- sorry, the hour changed and some of the shows listed above are no longer on. -->
    <showdetails>
        <nameofshow>Black Hawk Down</nameofshow>
        <information>An American mission to capture the top aides of a Somali warlord goes awry when
            enemy forces shoot down two Black Hawk helicopters and surround the soldiers on the
            ground. The ensuing firefight is a merciless 15-hour ordeal and the longest ground
            battle involving American soldiers since the Vietnam War.</information>
        <nameofshow>Tyler Perry's Good Deeds</nameofshow>
        <information>Upstanding and engaged businessman Wesley (Tyler Perry) finds his upcoming
            marriage thrown into question when his connection with a down-on-her-luck cleaning woman
            turns unexpectedly romantic. </information>
    </showdetails>
    <filterforhd>
        <options>1080p,720p,480p,standard</options>
    </filterforhd>
</tvlisting>
```

This is the DTD I have made my teacher said this looked completely fine, but it still feels like this is missing a thing where it could make this a better code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT tvlisting (changelocation+,date?,time?,searchlisting+,tabs*,legend?,tableofshows+,showdetails,filterforhd+) >
<!ELEMENT changelocation (provider?) >
<!ELEMENT provider (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT date (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT time (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT searchlisting (channelsearch+) >
<!ELEMENT channelsearch (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT tabs (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT legend (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT tableofshows (sation+, name+,timeaired+) >
<!ELEMENT sation (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT timeaired (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT showdetails (nameofshow+, information+) >
<!ELEMENT nameofshow (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT information (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT filterforhd (options+) >
<!ELEMENT options (#PCDATA) >
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the error you're getting, so I'm going to assume it's something like the following:

> Unexpected element "sation". The content of the parent element type
>   must match "(sation+, name+, timeaired+)".

What this is telling you is that the parent of `sation`, which is `tableofshows`, must match `(sation+,name+,timeaired+)`. That's because this is what you have declared for `tableofshows` in the DTD.

So what your declaration is saying is that `tableshows` must have one or more `sation` elements followed by one or more `name` elements followed by one or more `timeaired` elements.

(The `+` character means "one or more" and the `,` character means "followed by".)

That's not what you have in your XML. In your XML you have exactly one `sation` element followed by exactly one `name` element followed by exactly one `timeaired` element and this group (inside the parens) happens one or more times.

To have the declaration match your XML, you'd have to change it to:

```
<!ELEMENT tableofshows (sation, name, timeaired)+ >
```

It's the same thing with the `showdetails` element. Instead of one or more `nameofshow` elements followed by one or more `information` elements, you would need to change the declaration to one `nameofshow` element followed by one `information` element and that group can occur one or more times...

```
<!ELEMENT showdetails (nameofshow, information)+ >
```

That should fix your validation errors. Whether or not that is a good DTD design depends on what you're trying to accomplish and would be too broad to answer here.

Comment: Thank you, very much for the help this worked. Also, sorry if it was a little confusing I am new to this, asking questions online. But again thank you for the help :).